# Does my database design look right? M to M relationship

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, erd

[image]

My concern is over the table/entity `price_for_different_regions`. 
It's just I haven't studied database design systematically, most of the stuff I taught my self, it would be good to have some expert to have a look.
I'm using MySQL.

Comment: It's hard to tell without knowing what you are trying to model. The different category and price_category tables look fishy, though. If they only differ in the category label and are structurally identical elsewhere, they should be combined in one table.

Comment: Services in different categories have different attributes, and there are exclusive offers in different categories with different prices.

Comment: one category table is enough. Is there any specific reason for 3?

Comment: Product/Service within each category have different properties, so they are separated into different tables.

Comment: `price_c_category` and `_s` -- do these correspond to `c_category` and `s_cat...`? If yes, why is `price_d_cat` and `n_cat` unmatched?